# Javascript: How to store an object in a reference

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am getting highly confused.

I created an object,

```
var recipe = {name:"", price:10, details:"", img_path:""};
```

and I created a function that it's something like a constructor. It gives values to the object's properties,

```
function recipeInstantiation( name, price, details, img_path){
        recipe.name = name;
        recipe.price = price;
        recipe.details=details;
        recipe.img_path = img_path;
        // I dont know what to return here
        //maybe return recipe;
}
```

And then I need to pass recipe object to a reference,

var recipe2 = recipe;

Is that correct?

Comment: Instead of recipe.name and such, use this.name and then return this

Comment: All objects are references. If you assign two variables to the same object then modifying either variable will affect that one object. So with that, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try it yourself?  You should be doing your own basic research and trying things out before posting here.  Then, you can post here only about things that did not work or specific things that got you confused.

Comment: `// I dont know what to return here // maybe return recipe;` What you need to do is ask yourself what you need *returned*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objects are reference types and your class definition should follow javascript language constructs and conventions (i.e use pascal case for classes)

go here and learn
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

```
----------------------------------

    //class definition that describes a recipe
    function Recipe( name, price, details, img_path){
    //javascript use this keyword to define data fields.
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.details=details;
            this.img_path = img_path;

    }


    function displayRecipe(recipe){
         //display recipe as html
    }


----------------------------------
    var newReceipe = new Recipe("Pasta", 1000, "Something", "img/pasta.jpg");
    displayRecipe(newReceipe )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is supposed to do with this answer other than go to another website to learn JavaScript? OP is using object literal notation. You've added an object constructor without additional info as to why.

Answer (score 1):

`var recipe2 = recipe;`

You are correct. With the above, modifying any values in `recipe2` will also modify the values of `recipe` because several types in JavaScript (such as arrays and objects) are passed as references.

(Just FYI, if you *don't* want to pass `recipe` as a reference in some other use case, you should create a new object that copies all of `recipe`'s values, but that is out of the scope of this question.)

Comment: FYI you are right about the last, that is exactly what I need. I assume in JS there is no such thing as creating a class and then making objects right?

Comment: @Skemelio I'd suggest you read more about JavaScript. [Constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) are very common and act a lot like classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

With a **class** (First letter in uppercase). Use **this** to *initialize*

```
function Recipe(name, details, ...) {
    this.name = name,
    this.details = details,
    ...
}
```

Add a function to the class with **prototype**:

```
Recipe.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return obj;
}
```

Complete example:

```
function Recipe(name, price, details, img_path) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.details = details;
        this.img_path = img_path;
}

Recipe.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return {
        name: this.name,
        price: this.price,
        details: this.details,
        img_path: this.img_path
    }
}

var recipe1 = new Recipe("tomatonoodles", 7.99, "without gluten", "img/tomato.jpg");
var info = recipe1.getInfo();

alert(info);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, if I only could characterize two answers as correct...

Comment: If this answer was helpfull, you can upvote it!

Comment: Of course @Peter Leger!

Answer (score 0):

This is more functional way.

```
const newRecipe = (name, price, details, img_path) => {
  const obj = {};
  obj.name = name;
  obj.price = price;
  obj.details = details;
  obj.img_path = img_path;
  return obj;
}

const recipe1 = newRecipe('pasta', 1000, 'something', 'img/pasta.jpg');
console.log(recipe1);
```